# How can I generate this custom URL more succinctly in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

- I've set up the following route in Rails 3

`get '/:user_id/wants/:id' => 'wanted_items#public_view', :as => 'public_wanted_item'`

- Which gives the following in Rake Routes:

```
public_wanted_item GET    /:user_id/wants/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"wanted_items", :action=>"public_view"}
```

- And it produces the following URL, which is exactly what I want:

`/username/wants/itemname`

The problem is that in order to generate this in my views, I have to user a pretty verbose construct, where I specify `:user_id` and `:id` explicitly:

`ruby-1.9.2-p0 :012 > app.public_wanted_item_path(:user_id => item.user, :id => item)`

Is there any way I can make this call more concise, as I will be using it a lot in my application?

Thanks

---

**Edit:  I found a solution that works..  Pasted below**

It seems to work just as well if I use the following construct, which was what I was hoping for.. .. though I'm not sure exactly why it works..

`ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > app.public_wanted_item_path item.user,  item`

Because the next one doesn't work, but throws an error:

`ruby-1.9.2-p0 :004 > app.public_wanted_item_path([item.user,  item])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a job for an application helper. You could add something like:

```
def item_path_for(item)
    app.public_wanted_item_path(:user_id => item.user, :id => item)
end
```

to your `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` and then you could use

```
<%= item_path_for(pancakes) %>
```

in your views (or the HAML equivalent) or

```
include ApplicationHelper
#...
path = item_path_for(pancakes)
```

elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.public_wanted_item_path(:user_id => item.user.id, :id => item.id)
```

Comment: Thanks.. but this is actually more verbose than what I already had...  ?